# Boolean Algebra laws of deduction question

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

I have a question in which I'm a little stuck at answering, could anyone help?

```
Using the laws of deduction, show that the following statement is correct.

¬(A ∨ ¬B) ↔ B ∧ ¬A
```

Do I just use truth tables or is there more behind the law?

Comment: Presumably the text where you found the exercise will contain a definition of what it considers "the laws of deduction" to be. This is not a standard technical term with a universal definition; instead each author will set up his own rules, and is then free to call them THE laws of deduction, as long as the _results_ of his rules agree with the results of everyone else's various rule sets (which is usually the case).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, okay thank you. The book I have is a little disjointed in places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$¬(A ∨ ¬B)$ - Premise

$¬(B ∧ ¬A)$ - Assumption

$B$ - Assumption

$B ∧ ¬A$ - Rule of Conjunction

$⊥$ - Principle of Non-Contradiction

$¬B$ - Reductio ad Absurdum

$¬A$ - Assumption

$B ∧ ¬A$ - Rule of Conjunction

$⊥$ - Principle of Non-Contradiction

$A$ - Reductio ad Absurdum

$A ∨ ¬B$ - Rule of Addition

$⊥$ - Principle of Non-Contradiction

$B ∧ ¬A$ - Reductio ad Absurdum

[De Morgan's Laws (Logic)/Disjunction of Negations/Formulation 1/Reverse Implication](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_Laws_(Logic)/Disjunction_of_Negations/Formulation_1/Reverse_Implication)

[Definition:Natural Deduction](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Natural_Deduction)